# GPU for gaming, good VR support and ML on Linux

Tags: graphics-cards, gaming, linux

I **don't** want NVIDIA, I have experienced first hand its terrible VR support (Alyx, after many months, still runs like garbage on 2080ti) and even for non-VR games NVIDIA is usually much slower in supporting new games (e.g. Doom Eternal, Cyberpunk 2077).

I would prefer GPU having an open source driver. Good Linux support is a hard requirement (I don't use any other OS).

My price range is around 700$ (I don't want to go over 1000$).

I would like to try to get into machine learning (probably pytorch or tensorflow), so the GPU should be supported in at least one of those.

I was looking at 6800xt from AMD, but I don't know if it is supported in ML libraries. I know for sure it doesn't have CUDA (since it's NVIDIA tech) and sadly generic OpenCL doesn't seem to be supported in any mainstream ML library I checked. I saw mentions of ROCm for ML on AMD, but I didn't manage to find a complete list of supported cards. On NVIDIA, CUDA support is on every (at least mid to high range) gaming card, but I have no idea about AMD cards and their alternative to CUDA.

I hope I am asking in a correct place. Any recommendations, corrections and explanations (I am not that knowledgeable in hardware) are welcome.